# Ember.js Unable to find view at path when returning to route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple example ember.js app and I want to include a view on the index template.

This works for the initial render.

When I link to a second route and return back to the original I get the error **Unable to find view at path 'App.testView'**

Example code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z3AH/6/)

The HTML page...

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Test Layout</h1>
    {{outlet}}        
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Index Template</h2>
    <p>{{#linkTo test}}test route{{/linkTo}}</p>
    <div>{{view App.testView}}</div>    
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    <h2>Test Template</h2>
    <p>{{#linkTo index}}index route{{/linkTo}}</p>        
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="testview">
    <p>Test View</p>
</script>
```

The Javascript...

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("test");
});

App.testView = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'testview'
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z3AH/12/)

Using `Ember.View.extend` instead of `Ember.View.create` will fix this issue.

According to the [Ember API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view) for the `{{view}}` helper you need to pass it a class, not an instance.  The helper will create a new instance of the `View` and insert it.

Comment: Thanks c4p but still have a problem. JSFiddle was playing up so I posted an old version.  I already got that far... in your JSFiddle click the link to go to test state then back again and you still get the error. JSFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/4z3AH/6/

Comment: @jimcode I updated the answer and updated the fiddle to fix it.

Comment: I can see that this is how the code should work but wondering WHY they have designed the templates to require a class not an instance but for normal rendering of a view you want an instance.

This page uses an instance... http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/

and this page uses a class... http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/

Comment: @jimcode the first example is not using the `{{view}}` helper, it is reading a property directly from a view instance.

Comment: Was still trying to understand why it is like that but I think I have it.  When you use the view helper you have the option of passing in data that the helper uses to instantiate and render the view.  When dealing with the view directly you can obviously manage that yourself when you create it.  Anyway thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

one simple syntax mistake am able to identify is path attribute not added. Update the code Router.map() with this

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("test",{path:"/"});
});
```

Comment: The original router code is fine, an `index` template is defined which is loaded correctly.

Comment: Yes I agree with c4p this isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: oops ok..didnt go thgh the complete code...let me check once again

Comment: The JSFiddle wasn't illustrating the problem properly - I have now updated the link.  It works first time but when you link to the /test route and then back to / (index) the view can;t be found. http://jsfiddle.net/4z3AH/6/